How to keep the reactivity of data when passing it into a function?
Suppose my component looks like this:
<script setup lang="ts">
interface FileMetadata {
  owner: string,
  location: string,
  size: number,
  // And around 50 mores...
}

interface File {
  fileName: string,
  metadata: FileMetadata
}

const file = defineModel<File>({ required: true });

const buildControls = (metadata: FileMetadata) => {
  return [
    {
      label: 'Owner',
      model: metadata.owner,  // Correct so?
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      label: 'Location',
      model: metadata.location,  // Correct so?
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      label: 'Size',
      model: metadata.size,  // Correct so?
      type: 'number'
    },
    // And around 50 mores...
  ];
};

const controls = buildControls(file.value.metadata);  // Value is already unpack here
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for=(item, idx) in controls>
    <v-text-field v-model="item[idx].model" :label="item[idx].label" :type="item[idx].type" />
  </div>
</template>

This component takes a File object via its v-model, renders the view to allow users to edit its metadata. Whenever the model changes (another file was passed), the values of the text fields should be changed accordingly. And whenever users change values in the text fields, its corresponding values in the model must be changed as well. So, it's a two-way binding.
The view is rendered fine, but I cannot change values of the textboxes (it always changes back to its initial values when it loses its focus). I suppose because when the buildControls() function is called, the file is already unpacked, which makes it lose the reactivity. But if I do not unpack it (by accessing its .value), I cannot access its metadata attribute.
If I make the controls reactive by doing
const controls = reactive(buildControls(file.value.metadata));

then I can change the values in text fields, but the file model is not updated accordingly.
In my idea, the value of the  model key should be a Ref object. But somehow I cannot achieve it.
A possible solution is to store the key name of the FileMetadata only instead of the object in the model key. Then, it can be access later in the template as file.metadata[item.model]. However, I do not like this approach. Why can't I just simply store an object instead?
What did I do wrong here? What is the correct way to keep the reactivity of the data?

If you want to have reactivity, you need to tell it to Vue by using ref. Vue does not track a regular JS object in the same way as it does a reactive value. If the values are changed back, it's probably because you overwrite their value in the DOM but the virtual DOM that Vue is using for the real DOM overwrites it. Either opt-out of Vue whatsoever and handle the reactivity yourself or opt-in fully and use ref. There is a distinction between a ref and a regular object so that Vue doesn't need to use resources tracking something that is not worth being tracked.

I know what you meant. But the file object itself is already reactive. I think the problem is when I access its field using file.value.metadata, it's not reactive anymore because of the .value. In the template, we can simply write file.metadata, but it's not the case in the setup script.

Oh indeed! I'm not sure how defineModel but assuming it's all working as expected, I guess that one way would be to wrap the value (metadata.owner etc...) into a ref, I understand that it's not desired at all to redefine it. Hence, since you're passing metadata.value properly as a ref here, aren't you supposed to have model: metadata.value.owner so that it's unwraps the value of the ref? If a function receives a ref and you do not destructure or do anything crazy with it, it should keep its reactivity AFAIK. Each nested object of a ref should be reactive.

@TrietDoan The problem is that controls is not reactive, not file. The way it should be written depends on how it's supposed to work, which is unclear. Why is defineModel used? This is not shown.

@EstusFlask So, it should be controls = ref(buildControls(...))?. defineModel was used because when this component is used, I want its user to pass the file to v-model. I suppose we can just consider it as a normal ref in this case.

Refs are commonly overused without a reason. It's reactive(buildControls(...)). I mean v-model presumes that you emit changed value. If you intend to do this it in some way when you change controls, this could affect two-way binding. It's unclear if controls and model value is supposed to be synchronized. What is supposed to happen if you both changed controls and updated file value arrives? If nothing then it's as simple as reactive(...), no other changes are needed

controls and model value must be synchronized. If model changed, controls must be re-built, which can be achieved by using watchEffect. But with the usage of reactive, does the model get updated when values on textfields changes?

@TrietDoan No, it won't, and it would be bad if this were possible due to object structure, because this would mean that you mutate an object that came from a prop. For one-way sync you could use a computed, but here you need a watcher. "controls must be re-built" - if it needs to be reassigned and not merged, this is the case for a ref, so you could do controls.value = buildControls(file.value.metadata)

But then, how can I keep the model updated when the values in textbox changes? There is no emit mechanism in my component.

@TrietDoan Use @, otherwise users can't see the notifications if they closed the tab. Consider updating the question with your whole case explained, I'd expect that a possible solution vastly depends on the details. From what you describe, I'd expect that it would be better to explicitly have event listener for v-text-field that both updates controls and emits file update to a parent. Doing this the way you tried to do with v-model would make it much harder because you need to track changes in controls to emit them, you can't easily do this when you have v-model="item[idx].model"

This way you probably don't need buildControls in its current form, i.e. it would be better to separate "model" and the properties that aren't changed

I will. Could you post your answer? I'm still stuck to update the model when text field values change.

@TrietDoan I had similar cases with forms, posted the supposed way to do this. Basically this isn't a good case to use v-model both on v-text-field and the current component

controls is not reactive, this needs to be changed:
const controls = ref();
...
controls.value = buildControls(...);

Or:
const controls = reactive(buildControls(...));

But the problem is that controls is intended for two-way synchronization with file, its structure makes it hard to implement. This is a general problem with storing mixed mutable and static data, there are not enough reasons to keep it together.
If the component is supposed to emit file changes to a parent based on the changes that v-model="item[idx].model"` there will be problems with tracking specific changes.
There should be a list of metadata keys that both static and mutable data could use. The suggested way is to keep static field data as a constant, so the types could derive from it for extra type safety (ValidateKeys can be implemented like shown here):
const fileMetaFields = {
  owner: {
    label: 'Owner',
    type: 'text'
  },
  ...
}

type FileMetaKeys = keyof typeof fileMetaFields;

type FileMeta = ValidateKeys<FileMetaKeys, {
  owner: string,
  ...
}

Additional utility types could be written to automatically map type: 'text' to string type.
The component may not need own state if it's supposed to update parent's model. v-model in v-text-field limits the ways in which the model could be updated, so it needs to be desugared:
  function updateModelField({ key, value }) {
    emit('update:modelValue', {
      ...file.value,
      metadata: {
        ...file.value.metadata
        [key]: value
      },
    });
  }

  ...

  <div v-for=(field, key) in fileMetaFields>
    <v-text-field
      :label="field.label"
      :modelValue="file.value.metadata[key]" />
      @update:modelValue="updateModelField({ key, value: $event })"
      ... 

This indicates the problem with file. In order to prevent model prop from being mutated in a child and do this in a parent like Vue two-way binding requires, the whole object needs to be cloned to change one field. This is inefficient and can be avoided by providing a child with only data it needs (metadata instead of file) and updating file in a parent with custom event rather than v-model.
So it would be in the child:
  const props = defineProps<{ data: FileMeta }>();

  function updateModelField({ key, value }) {
    emit('update:field', { key, value });
  }

In a parent:
<FileMetaForm
  :data="file.metadata"
  @update:field="file.metadata[$event.key] = $event.value"
>


If I understand your answer correctly, the idea is to store a list of key and use it to find the proper model via file.metadata[key], which is the same approach as I described in my question as a possible solution.

No, the idea is to store static and dynamic data separately. You iterate any of them with v-for and access data from another collection with a key. Keeping them separate makes it simpler and more efficient than making a soup out of them in "controls" and trying to unmix it later. Also you discarded a key for a particular control in your code because item.model doesn't contain "size", etc key names, so file.metadata[item.model] wouldn't be a solution

If you want keep reactivity of data, you can use computed，modify your code as follows:
<script setup lang="ts">
interface FileMetadata {
  owner: string,
  location: string,
  size: number,
  // And around 50 mores...
}

interface File {
  fileName: string,
  metadata: FileMetadata
}

const file = defineModel<File>({ required: true });

const buildControls = (metadata: FileMetadata) => {
  return [
    {
      label: 'Owner',
      model: metadata,  // Correct so?
      type: 'text',
      field: "owner"
    },
    {
      label: 'Location',
      model: metadata,  // Correct so?
      type: 'text',
      field: "location"
    },
    {
      label: 'Size',
      model: metadata,  // Correct so?
      type: 'number',
      field: "size"
    },
    // And around 50 mores...
  ];
};

const controls = buildControls(file.value.metadata);  // Value is already unpack here
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="item in controls">
    <v-text-field v-model="item.model[item.field]" :label="item.label" :type="item.type" />
  </div>
</template>


This approach is not two-way binding. When the values of text fields change, the metadata inside the file is not updated accordingly.

I apologize for giving you the wrong approach. The reason two-way binding fails is because you are assigning a primitive type rather than a reference type.
I've updated my response, which might solve your issue.
